Tracking Group Properties Through Representation Theory
I’m new to representation theory and am exploring how to track certain properties of finite groups within this context. I am dealing with a group that satisfies a specific definition related to properties such as solubility and nilpotency and others. I’m particularly interested in methods for monitoring these properties through representation theory. Are there established techniques or standard practices for tracking properties like solubility, nilpotency, and others? Additionally, how can one ensure that essential properties are preserved or correctly identified during this process?
Any reference will be helpful.

I don't really understand this question. Are you asking if the representations of a group can tell you if it's solvable or nilpotent? What does "monitor" and "track" mean here? What is the "process" you're talking about?

@SteveD Yes.
By "monitor" and "track," I mean identifying and verifying these properties through representation theory. The "process" refers to analyzing group representations to see if these properties can be inferred or confirmed. Are there standard techniques in representation theory that help with this?

You might want to check this MO post (answers and comments). Solvability and nilpotency are deducible from the character table.
